# Filter for a class in Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am using two different libraries( jar files) in my project and they contain a common class? So i am getting this error on release build

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':rr_android:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [D:\git\rr\rr_android\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] (Can't read [D:\git\rr\rr_android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\rr\Abc resources\unspecified\libs\commons-codec-1.4.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-codec-1.4.jar:org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone$DoubleMetaphoneResult.class]))
```

How do i exclude one of the files?

I am adding this line to exclude the duplicating class but the error is not going away

```
-injars  ../Abc resources/libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar( !org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone.DoubleMetaphoneResult)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use file **path**, instead of FQN of the class in the filter.

```
-injars  ../Abc resources/libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar(!org/apache/commons/codec/language/DoubleMetaphone/DoubleMetaphoneResult*)
```